# Unable to import mock in test using pytest

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, python-mock

I have a test file `tests.py`. Currently, to help isolate the problem, the file contains only the following line:

```
from mock import Mock
```

When I try to run this file with `pytest`:

```
$ py.test tests.py
```

I get the following error output:

```
tests.py:1: in <module>
    from mock import Mock
E   ImportError: No module named mock
=========================== 1 error in 0.00 seconds ============================
```

If I run the file with `python`:

```
$ python tests.py
```

I do not get this error. Similarly, if I open an interactive interpreter, I am able to import `mock` without issue. **Why am I not able to access `mock` in this context?**

Comment: have you checked your PATH variable, maybe you have another python binary running ?

Comment: Thank you @MichaelKarotsieris, that put me on the right track. I was in a virtualenv, but pytest was installed through my OS package manager (`apt` on Ubuntu). When I ran the `py.test` command, my virtual environment was *not* in `sys.path`, and that is where `mock` was installed. I had to remove the version of pytest installed through `apt` and install it through `pip` in my virtualenv in order for it to work...

Comment: cool! Nice to help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the version of Pytest that I was using was installed through `apt`, while my version of `mock` was installed through `pip` in a virtual environment. On the suggestion of **@MichaelKarotsieris**, I checked the contents of `sys.path` after running my tests with Pytest (I used the `--pdb` option to pop into the `pdb` debugger after the error was  raised):

```
$ py.test tests.py --pdb
...
(Pdb) import sys
(Pdb) sys.path
```

From this I found that although my virtual environment was active, that environment was *not* in `sys.path`.

Next, I tried installing pytest in my virtual environment through pip:

```
(my_env) $ pip install pytest
```

However, with this step alone the version of Pytest installed through `apt` was still being used, so I decided to just remove it:

```
(my_env) $ sudo apt remove --purge python-pytest
```

After this, running the `py.test` command worked as expected.

In hindsight, I suppose I could have kept the version of Pytest installed through `apt`, and just ran the executable from the virtualenv directly:

```
(my_env) $ /path/to/my_env/bin/py.test tests.py
```